# Vite bundle into two js files, with one file empty

Tags: typescript, vite

I have tried to customize `vite.config.js` file, with the following content:

```
const ROOT_PATH = './'
const SRC_DIR = 'src'
const ASSETS_DIR = 'assets'
const SCRIPTS_DIR = 'scripts'
const STYLES_DIR = 'styles'

const entries = [
  path.join(ROOT_PATH, SRC_DIR, STYLES_DIR, '*'),
  path.join(ROOT_PATH, SRC_DIR, SCRIPTS_DIR, 'entries', '*')
].map(pattern => glob.sync(pattern, { onlyFiles: true }))

export default defineConfig({
  ...,
  build: {
    sourcemap: true,
    target: 'ES2015',
    outDir: path.join(ROOT_PATH, ASSETS_DIR),
    assetsDir: '',
    emptyOutDir: false,
    rollupOptions: {
      input,
      output: {
        entryFileNames: '[name].js',
        assetFileNames: '[name].[ext]'
      }
    }
  },
})
```

Here is my code structure:

```
└── src
    ├── scripts
    │   └── entries
    │       └── main.ts
    └── styles
        └── main.css
```

When I run build, there are two js files getting built:

```
assets/main.css   0.27 kB │ gzip:  0.18 kB
assets/main2.js   0.00 kB │ gzip:  0.02 kB
assets/main.js   50.97 kB │ gzip: 20.61 kB
```

Could you please help me to fix this problem?